# JSON returns string instead of array after parsing

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, stringify

I have a .csv file containing 2 columns - company and standard software appID. I read each line and use the company as a key then the values are array of appIDs.

Expected Output:

`{"Company A" : ["1","2","3"], "Company B" : ["2","3"]}`

Here's the actual code and logic:

**Step 1: Read .csv, store values as array and save to localStorage as JSON string:**

```
$(document).load('./software/software_standard.csv',function(data){
    var lines = data.split('\n');
    var software_object = {};
    for(i=1;i<lines.length;i++) {
        currentline = lines[i].split(',');
        if(software_object [currentline[0]]){
            var array = software_object[currentline[0]];
            array.push(currentline[1]);
        }
        else {
            var array = new Array();
            array.push(currentline[1])
            software_object[currentline[0]] = array;
        }
    }
    var JSON_string = JSON.stringify(software_object);
    localStorage.setItem('object',JSON_string);
})
```

**Step 2: Get item on localStorage - var x = LocalStorage.getItem('object'):**

```
{"Test - Tokyo Tokyo":"[\"1\", \"2\", \"3\", \"4\", \"5\", \"6\", \"7\", \"8\", \"9\"]","Account 7":"[\"1\"]","BPI":"[\"6\"]","":"[\"\"]"}
```

**Step 3: Parse returned item - var y = JSON.parse(x):**

```
{Test - Tokyo Tokyo: "["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]", Account 7: "["1"]", BPI: "["6"]", "": "[""]"}
```

**Step 4: Access first key - y["Test - Tokyo Tokyo"]:**

The output was a string: `"["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]"`

**THE PROBLEM:**

The expected output should be an array of numbers - not a string. I have scoured Stackoverflow but couldn't find an exact match. I am trying to solve this by removing characters 3 characters ", [, and ] to get a value like this:

`y["Test - Tokyo Tokyo"] = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9"`

then use `.split(',')` to convert that back to an array.

Is there a simpler solution to this?

Comment: Try `JSON.parse(y["Test - Tokyo Tokyo"])`

Comment: Please share a csv line.

Comment: can't reproduce, please provide a fiddle or Pen with a sample of your csv

Comment: If you would have given a sample of the CSV, I am willing to bet you would have had more answers within minutes of asking.

Comment: Did you call `JSON.stringify` for each array before calling JSON.stringify for `sofware_object`?

There's just no way that an array will transform into a string during `JSON.stringify`. The only way is if you `stringify` the array values into  string first.

For instance, see the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6o5yksb5/1/

Comment: @RyukLee: I actually tried your solution and it worked.

Comment: @Taki: I don't see any option to upload a local .csv on jsfiddle. I get an error when I try to load the .csv on Dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lge2xxipul0zirk/software_standard.csv?dl=0

The error is: Failed to load https://www.dropbox.com/s/lge2xxipul0zirk/software_standard.csv?dl=0: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: use [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue)

Comment: @Taki I'll try to learn more about plnkr but anyway - the solution for now is provided by Ryuk Lee.

Answer (score 0):

`{"Test - Tokyo Tokyo":"[\"1\", \"2\", \"3\", \"4\", \"5\", \"6\", \"7\", \"8\", \"9\"]","Account 7":"[\"1\"]","BPI":"[\"6\"]","":"[\"\"]"}`

The value of "Test - Tokyo Tokyo" is a string

If it was an array it would be like this:

`{"Test - Tokyo Tokyo":["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"],"Account 7":["1"],"BPI":["6"],"":[""]}`